# Nested IF Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am currently using the following formula i.e. **=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>4,A2+1,A2)** to change the number when I drag this formula downsdie of the rows.

For Example: in this case for every five rows number will change i.e. A1 to A5 it will **1** and A6 to A10 it will be **2** and A11 to A15 it will be **3** etc.

Just wanted to know is it possible to extend the same formula, so along with adding 1 number for every five rows it should also skip 2 numbers for every 60 rows.

For Example: if the 60 row is number 12, then 61st row should be 15 and 120 row will be 26 and 121 row should be 124 etc.

Can someone please help me with this formula?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: floor((row-1)/5)+1 + floor((row-1)/60)*2

Comment: I am not sure how to use this formula

Comment: I am getting the following error message stating "You've entered few arguments for this function"

Comment: I was just giving you an equation. But I think in Excel you have to add an extra 0 argument to the floor function to tell it which decimal place. So try `=floor((row()-1)/5, 0) + 1 + floor((row()-1)/60, 0) * 2`

Comment: If you want a result for `every` repeated of a value, check my answer ;).

Comment: I change my answer with thanks to @shawnt00.

Comment: I am actually linking the other worksheet cells nearly 30,000 rows.  So for every 60 rows, formula should skip two numbers, because in row 61 and 62, there are subtotals in the other sheet, hence I don't want to use/link those rows.

Comment: Sorry.  I may be confusing you too much.  Hence I am attaching a test file which has formulas in it.  I have updated the file in the below link

Comment: Sorry.  I may be confusing you too much.  Hence I am attaching a test file which has formulas in it.  I have updated the file in the below link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAVx7KDQJ2sN2x6em5fWU5wRTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you look at the formula, for every 61st row I have updated the number +3 manually.  This should come with the help of formula

Comment: I forgot it to add 1 point in 5th row and add it to `A` in result, can you check my edited answer ?

Comment: As I saw your answer I think @shawnt00 answer should be work correct. but any changes to your data will cause fault.

Comment: @pnuts Actually I edit his post by correct format of `FLOOR` in excel if you change that `floor` to my `FLOOR` it can work I add correct format as comment there, now.

Comment: I found that you just want a column not a related column so I delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number starts at one.

Then get the cell's row number and subtract one. Divide that number by 5 and discard the fractional part (or the remainder). So numbers from 0 to 4 (which are rows 1 through 5) all get an increment of 0, 5 to 9 get 1, and so on. Similar logic with multiples of 60 except that the counting is doubled.

```
=1 + floor((row()-1)/5, 1) + floor((row()-1)/60, 1) * 2
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but still I am getting the "#DIV/0!" error when I use this formula :(

Comment: `=1 + (FLOOR((ROW()-1);5) / 5) + (FLOOR((ROW()-1);60) / 60) * 2 ` this can be usable in Excel ;).

Comment: This is what I wanted shA.  Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: This was really a great help and saves lot of hours for me.  Because I have to apply this formula for 20+ workbooks  and  each workbook will have 20,000+ rows.  Thank you once again :)

Comment: As I had noted in a comment earlier I always forget Excel allows for rounding to any number. Most systems I run into look for the second argument as the number of decimals. I'm glad you got it sorted out after I went to bed.